# Empty Response: Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions [MAC]

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to setup monitoring for Mac and am having a few issues. Currently, the Availability tab on Zabbix 3.2 has ZBX highlighted in red with the error mentioned in the title: So far:

- I have done countless searches and have ensured the Server and ServerActive IP address is correct
- I have moved zabbix_agentd.conf moved from local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf to /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

This seems to be the only 2 solutions but they are not working. I have restarted the agent

Does anyone have any experience on solving this issue for OSX?

Comment: In this case, the "Server" parameter does not match the IP of the incoming server connection. For the configuration changes, the agent must be restarted. When you say that you do not know how to restart the agent, how did you install it, how did you start it?

Comment: I have checked the Server parameter a dozen times and it is definitely correct. I installed it by simply extracting .tar.gz and running the install script. it seems to have worked since the .log file is responding to changes.

Comment: I go to usr/local/sbin/zabbix_agentd to start the process, more specifically.

Comment: What does "log file is responding to changes" mean? The "Server" parameter might match your server IP, but are you sure there is no address translation or anything else going on? You can also set DebugLevel to 4, restart the agent and see what IP it sees the connections as coming from. Alternatively, check with tcpdump or Wireshark on port 10050 for incoming connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, write permissions were needed for the log file.

Answer (score -2):

This error is not a permission error or a server side error. This is related to network hops.

First enable debug level in your Zabbix agent conf:
nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

Uncomment below line and change it to number 4

```
Debug Level=4
```

Then restart your agent service

tail the log file

```
tail -f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
```

If your log shows any rejected IP hop, you need to white-list that IP on your agent conf file in two places.

```
server=zabbixserverIP,LasthopIP
ServerActive=zabbixserverIP,LasthopIP
```

The main thing is that the first network hop in your routing found in your Zabbix serverIP range needs to be included in the white-list.